# Trying to displaying whats on listview on a textbox WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, listview

I have a WPF with a listview filled with names that are coming from a database. On the listview(gridview) are 3 coloumns (Name, Age, Grade). What I'm trying to do is when I select a person on the listview I want their information to display in textboxes. I'm not sure if its better to do it through code or XAML, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Heres what I have:

```
          namespace Camp_
 {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CampersPage.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class CampersPage : Page
{
    MainWindow _parentForm;

    public CampersPage(MainWindow parent)
    {
        _parentForm = parent;
        InitializeComponent();


        for (int i = 0; i < _parentForm.allCampers.Count; i++)
        {


            listViewCampers.Items.Add(new { Name = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getName(), Age = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getAge(), Grade = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getGrade() });

        }
    }


        private void listViewCampers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _parentForm.allCampers.Count; i++)
        {


                //  txtName.Text = listViewCampers.SelectedItem.Col1.toString();
            txtName.Text = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getName();
                txtAge.Text = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getAge();
                txtGrade.Text = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getGrade();


        }

        }
    }
  }


        // _parentForm.ListToText();
           // for (int i = 0; i < _parentForm.testClass.g1.members.Count; i++)
        /*
            {  
                if (listViewCampers.SelectedItem == _parentForm.testClass.g1.members[i].getName())
                { 
                    txtName.Text = _parentForm.testClass.g1.members[i].getName();
                    txtAge.Text = "" + _parentForm.testClass.g1.members[i].getAge();
                    txtGrade.Text = "" + _parentForm.testClass.g1.members[i].getGrade();
                    txtRequest1.Text = "None";
                    txtRequest2.Text = "None";
                    txtRequest3.Text = "None";

                    Camper[] x = _parentForm.testClass.g1.members[i].getRequests();

                    if (x[0] != null && x[1] != null && x[2] != null)
                    {
                        txtRequest1.Text = "" + x[0].getName();
                        txtRequest2.Text = "" + x[1].getName();
                        txtRequest3.Text = "" + x[2].getName();
            } } } 
    */

       //txtName.Text = listViewCampers.SelectedItem.Col1.toString();
        //txtAge.Text = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getAge();
        //txtGrade.Text = "" + _parentForm.allCampers[i].getGrade();
```

Heres the XAML:

```
     <Page x:Class="Camp_.CampersPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="570"
Title="Campers Page" ShowsNavigationUI="False" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Camp_"  >

<Grid Name="camperGrid">
    <Grid.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC3D6F5" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEFF5FF" Offset="1" />
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>





        <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,40" Name="listViewCampers" Width="200" SelectionChanged="listViewCampers_SelectionChanged">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>



                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="100"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Width="40" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Grade" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Grade}" Width="40" />

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Grid Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="209,12,0,0" Name="infoGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="134*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="154*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,24,0,0" Name="lblName" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,46,0,0" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" AcceptsReturn="True" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,103,0,0" Name="txtAge" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="Age" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,75,0,0" Name="lblAge" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,27,0,0" Name="txtGrade" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Label Content="Grade" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,0,0,0" Name="lblGrade" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,46,0,0" Name="txtRequest1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="Roommate Request #1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,24,0,0" Name="lblRequest" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,103,0,0" Name="txtRequest2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,27,0,0" Name="txtRequest3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Label Content="Roommate Request #2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,75,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Label Content="Roommate Request #3" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,0,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at using the [MVVM design pattern](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx) for a greater separation of concerns, which is going to make testing and reusing your codebase much easier.

In this instance, you can bind the values of the text boxes declaratively in XAML by binding the `DataContext` of a surrounding element (e.g. a `Grid` that surrounds your text boxes) to the `SelectedItem` of the `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what your saying but I've never done any of this kind of stuff before so honestly I'm not sure how to set the binding and what to set it to. I look at examples and they would just say Text = "{Binding Name}" Theres more to it but I don't know what

Comment: I would start by reading the MSDN documentation on data binding - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx. Then, when you have an understanding of that, you can read about the MVVM design at the link I have included. In MVVM, the DataContext of the view (i.e. your XAML UserControl or Window) would be an instance of your view model, so when you have a binding statement, e.g. {Binding Name} you are binding to a public property of your view model typically. Once you have an understanding of MVVM, I would look into using an MVVM framework to ease development.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned MVVM with Databinding is the way to go.

Here is a small working MVVM type sample that may point you in the right direction.

Check out the video linked to in the 3rd paragraph to help you along :) [MVVM - Jason Dollinger](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650)

And for more helpful WPF information check out [WPFTutorial.net](http://www.wpftutorial.net)

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBindingSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:WpfBindingSample.Models"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Person}" >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Person.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfBindingSample.Models
{
    public class Person : DependencyObject
    {


        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FirstName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FirstName", typeof(string), typeof(Person), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));



        public string LastName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LastNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LastNameProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LastName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LastNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LastName", typeof(string), typeof(Person), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));



    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using WpfBindingSample.Models;

namespace WpfBindingSample
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            People = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Person>();
        }

        public Person SelectedPerson
        {
            get { return (Person)GetValue(SelectedPersonProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedPersonProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedPerson.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPersonProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedPerson", typeof(Person), typeof(MainWindowViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    }
}
```